# How to create 20 random bytes of fixed length

Tags: java, byte, bit

I used the `random.nextBytes()` method and it generate random `bytes`. But i want every `byte` to have a fixed length of 8 bits. How do i do that?

```
    SecureRandom random=new SecureRandom(); 
    byte[] data=new byte[2];
    random.nextBytes(data);

    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(data[0]));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(data[1]));
```

This is the output i get

```
    1000
    110010
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by that? A byte **is** 8 bits.

Comment: A byte is 8 bit, by definition.  You can't have anything else.  Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Every `byte` does have a fixed length of 8 bits. Do you mean positive value? You can cast to int and add 128.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or you can do `x & 0xFF`

Comment: @PeterLawrey But that won't give you the range 0-255. True enough, OP might just want 0-127.

Comment: So, you want to pad those binary numbers with 0 so that they are 8 digits long?

Comment: Yes, I want every byte to have 8 digits

Comment: Format it to have 8 digits.  Java makes this a bit tricky to do, but there are 3-4 different techniques.  A couple that can be done entirely with toBinaryString and String methods.

Comment: My favorite is `Integer.toBinaryString(256+theByte).substring(1)`.

Comment: @hotlicks, I like this but it does not give the correct result for bytes > 128 (or < 0).

Comment: @dansalmo -- I guess you're right that it will fail for negative values.  `Integer.toBinaryString(256+(0xFF & theByte)).substring(1)` should work, though.  > 128 is not a problem.

Comment: (Forgot that `byte` is signed in Java.)

Comment: Slightly simpler: `Integer.toBinaryString(768+b).substring(2)`

Comment: Now that is really nice.  You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bytes in the array are already a fixed length of 8 bits.  If what you really mean is that you want to print them with a fixed length of 8 bits you can do this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(data[0] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(data[1] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
```

will print

```
00001000
00110010
```

The other suggestions will not work properly for values > 128 (or < 0) unless you add 512 and mask properly, then is is actually nicer:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((0x100|0xff&data[1]).substring(1))
```

I am adding this last part, giving credit to Hot Licks since it is the best I have seen.  It works with all types accepted by `Integer.toBinaryString()`.

```
Integer.toBinaryString(0x300+b).substring(2) //for b < 256
```

If you want a 16 bit result you can do:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(0x30000+bb).substring(2)  //for bb < 65536
```

Generalized for 1 to 62 bits for n < 2^62:

```
int bits = 8;
Long mask =  (1L << bits) - 1;
Long.toBinaryString((3L << bits) + (mask & n)).substring(2);
```

63 bits is a special case:

```
Long.toBinaryString((1L << bits) + (mask & n)).substring(1);
```

Comment: Did you try it when the number 129 was cast to a byte?  In that case the result is `"0000001"` instead of `"10000001"`.  `Integer.toBinaryString(256+theByte).substring(1)` only works correctly when `theByte` is an `int` or a `short`.

Comment: OK, that's just a part of it not working for negative numbers.

Comment: (It is confusing having `byte` signed, since we rarely think of them that way.)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simpler: `Integer.toBinaryString(768+b).substring(2)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a difference between binary and decimal. Normally, we think of a byte **by definition** as having 8 bits. Whereas, an ordinary 8 digit number must start with a non-zero digit (unless it is a business number like an ISBN), an 8-bit byte can start with a 0.

So it seems that you want the most significant bit to be 1 - I think.

Well there is a simple way to "fix" that: `number | 128`. And it shouldn't harm the randomness.

Comment: But decimal rarely exists in computers.  Hasn't been a decimal computer built in 40 years, probably.  (Granted, several hardware architectures include "decimal" instructions, but their use is restricted to RPG, COBOL, and a few other ancient languages.)

Comment: Sure, but I was just talking about decimal as it is used by humans.

Comment: Which is an important thing to remember.  When you do Integer.toBinaryString you're not converting from decimal to binary, but rather you're converting *from* binary to a character representation of that binary.